# Prove whether ¬∃xP(x) logically implies ¬∀xP(x) or not.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

So my logic is

¬∃xP(x)⟺ ∀x¬P(x)

and if ∀x¬P(x) is taken to be true, then for all x P(x) is false

and

¬∀xP(x)⟺ ∃x¬P(x)

which means that for some $x$, $P(x)$ is false

and if all $x$ is false, then that implies that some $x$ is false.

Is this correct?

Comment: Presumably you have been given some laws of manipulation?

Comment: What do you mean? Manipulation of the quantifiers? or for this question in general? If you mean this question, this is the whole thing.

Comment: @Brownie Laws of manipulation (or inference) in general, for example something that allows you to infer that $A$ is true if you know that $A\land B$ is true. Of course, here we are specifically interested in any such rules you have regarding $\forall$ and $\exists$

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been given any information like that.The question is posted as I received it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It seems that the approved edit might've accidentally changed parts of my question, it is fixed now. Could you please take a look at it again? I'm sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying a semantic argument, rather than a syntactic derivation.  Have you been taught any *rules of inference*, or are you at the stage of justifying the meaning for the symbols?

---

$\forall x~\lnot P(x)$ says every entity denies the predicate.

$\exists x~P(x)$ says some entity affirms the predicate.

If every entity denies the predicate, then we deny that some entity affirms the predicate. $$\forall x~\lnot P(x)\implies \lnot\exists x~P(x)$$

If no entity affirms the predicate, then every entity denies the predicate. $$\lnot \exists x~P(x)\implies\forall x~\lnot P(x)$$

Comment: It seems that the approved edit might've accidentally changed parts of my question, it is fixed now. Could you please take a look at it again? I'm sorry for the trouble